# Wifi and Ethernet same static IP at the same time

Tags: windows, networking, ip

I've old laptop working as my local webserver. I want to access the web applications via Wi-Fi (hotspot) and ethernet (crossover), and I want both adapters to have the same IP. Some web applications like WordPress don't work properly if the IP changed.

Is that possible to have both adapters have the same IP at the same time  on Windows?

Comment: No, you cannot use two duplicate IP addresses at the same time.

Comment: you're welcome. If you can provide a drawing or something of what your network looks like, there may be some way to set up NAT. There are no guarantees though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is funny looking back at my silly question!

As far as I know now, the thing I want can't be achieved (have 2 network interfaces on same machine with same IP address). There was a work around, a simple one.

Use a router which can provide me Wi-Fi and Ethernet connections using only one network interface on the "server" laptop

An extra for me was that I was able to have something like domain name (mylaptop.local) since I'm using DD-WRT on my router. I'm not sure if all routers can do this as I've never used non-wrt routers

Later I learned how to install and have my local BIND9 DNS server, which is much better than DHCP server for having different web-apps and different kind of servers other than webserver, like a mail server for example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use a laptop plugged into a hotspot to host apps (example: Wordpress). To do so you will need to log into the hotspot and configure port forwarding. To configure port forwarding you will need instructions specific to your hotspot. Port forwarding may not be available on all hotspots. Here is a general overview of how port forwarding works:

1) You will set a static, private IP on the laptop.

2) You will figure out which port or ports you want to forward. Wordpress is port 80 I think.

3) Within the hotspot, you will configure port forwarding to the private IP of the laptop for the port (or ports) needed. If you want to forward all ports, there usually a setting to set a DMZ host.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's not what I want.

Comment: What I've is a laptop running a hotspot on it using Connectify. I use this hotspot to access WordPress from mobile, and I've a PC connected to the laptop via Ethernet. The problem is each network adapter/interface have different IP address so WordPress don't work properly. I want to have the same IP address for both adapters/interfaces.

Comment: Is Wordpress running on the PC? Is the main function of the laptop to act as a hotspot? How do you get to the internet from the PC? And from the laptop?

Comment: WP and hotspot (share internet) is running on the laptop. I get the Internet on the laptop using 4G modem

Comment: In that case you would set up port forwarding within Connectify (if possible).